# asus ac68 merlin curl ignore http_proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, router

`asus ac68` is a router. I have installed the latest firmware(merlin) 384.11.

curl -V

```
curl 7.64.1 (arm-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2r zlib/1.2.5
Release-Date: 2019-03-27
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps tftp
Features: HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

set:

```
HISTFILE='/root/.ash_history'
HOME='/root'
HTTPS_PROXY='http://192.168.2.110:1920'
HTTP_PROXY='http://192.168.2.110:1920'
PATH='/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/kasim:/mmc/sbin:/mmc/bin:/mmc/usr/sbin:/mmc/usr/bin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/opt/usr/bin'
PPID='1679'
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/tmp/home/root'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLVL='1'
TERM='xterm-256color'
TMOUT='1200'
USER='xxxxx'
_='install'
http_proxy='http://192.168.2.110:1920'
https_proxy='http://192.168.2.110:1920'
```

wget is working good with proxy, but curl doesn't .
I have to add -x option . But there are many scripts which utlize curl , I can't check and modify every one , so I wonder how can I make curl work with system global proxy ?

PS: I don't have a usb driver to install Entware, update or install package is difficult .

Answer (score 1):

2 solutions to this :

- you can create a shell alias such as : `alias curl='curl --proxy http://[host]:[port]'`
- or define the proxy settings in a cURL config file : `echo 'proxy = [host]:[port]' > ~/.curlrc`

I've not been able to make this work using environment variables.

NB : your configuration defines `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` both as uppercase and lowercase variables, which looks pretty error-prone to me.

Comment: alias seems good idea. I have bash functions `proxyon` and `proxyoff` , which trend to make sure all softwares go through my proxy by settings . As I remember , some only work with uppercase variables .